# How to hide image with src in wkwebview when loading html in ios?

Tags: html, ios, css, webkit, wkwebview

I'm using WKWebView loading html string, some end of html string have a few of ugly image links, i want to hide them.

The css use to hide image, but not works.

```
.article img[src* = "/smilies/"],
.article img[src* = ".feedburner.com/~ff/"],
.article img[src* = ".feedburner.com/~r/"],
.article img[src* = ".feedblitz.com/"]
{
    display: none;
}
```

The sample html string with feedburner src i want to hide :

```
<div>
<a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?a=H9eoOCii8XI:sanX3-jfWnw:yIl2AUoC8zA"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"></a> <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?a=H9eoOCii8XI:sanX3-jfWnw:qj6IDK7rITs"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?d=qj6IDK7rITs" border="0"></a> <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?a=H9eoOCii8XI:sanX3-jfWnw:V_sGLiPBpWU"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?i=H9eoOCii8XI:sanX3-jfWnw:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"></a> <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?a=H9eoOCii8XI:sanX3-jfWnw:I9og5sOYxJI"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?d=I9og5sOYxJI" border="0"></a> <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?a=H9eoOCii8XI:sanX3-jfWnw:D7DqB2pKExk"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?i=H9eoOCii8XI:sanX3-jfWnw:D7DqB2pKExk" border="0"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way to achieve this is by using regular expressions. Mind you that this is really not ideal for long HTML files as it is not as efficient as a real HTML parser.

```
// The HTML you posted
NSString *HTML = @"<div>\n\t<a href=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?a=H9eoOCii8XI:sanX3-jfWnw:yIl2AUoC8zA\"><img src=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?d=yIl2AUoC8zA\" border=\"0\"></a> <a href=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?a=H9eoOCii8XI:sanX3-jfWnw:qj6IDK7rITs\"><img src=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?d=qj6IDK7rITs\" border=\"0\"></a> <a href=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?a=H9eoOCii8XI:sanX3-jfWnw:V_sGLiPBpWU\"><img src=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?i=H9eoOCii8XI:sanX3-jfWnw:V_sGLiPBpWU\" border=\"0\"></a> <a href=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?a=H9eoOCii8XI:sanX3-jfWnw:I9og5sOYxJI\"><img src=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?d=I9og5sOYxJI\" border=\"0\"></a> <a href=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?a=H9eoOCii8XI:sanX3-jfWnw:D7DqB2pKExk\"><img src=\"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Venturebeat?i=H9eoOCii8XI:sanX3-jfWnw:D7DqB2pKExk\" border=\"0\"></a>\n</div>";

// A string containing source of the images that you want to delete
NSString *source = @"http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/";

// Builds a pattern that matches the tags of the images you want to delete
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=\"%@.+?>", source];

// The actual delete operation
NSString *cleanHTML = [HTML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:pattern
                                                      withString:@""
                                                         options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, HTML.length)];

// Do what you want with the cleaned HTML (display it, ...)
NSLog(@"%@", cleanHTML);
```